# Work permit (Tier 2) - Impact on schengen application (nonEU)

Tags: schengen, uk, long-term, residency, working-visas

I have a Work Permit (Tier 2) for the UK for 2 years, and would like to travel to various countries in Europe whenever possible during this time. I have no EU Family Members.

- Would I be able to apply for a 5-Year Multiple Entry Schengen Visa using the Tier 2 Work Permit?
- Would it help if I become a Temporary Resident of the UK?

Comment: You could certainly apply (and get) a Schenge visa, including a multi-entry one, while residing in the UK on a Tier 2 visa (my wife did, more than once).  However you are not going to get visa that's valid beyond the validity of your UK visa.  If your UK visa is for 2 years and you're applying from inside UK, your best case will be a 1-year visa.  In reality, you probably won't get anything beyond 6 months.

Comment: If you have a T2, you are already temporarily resident in the UK.  But regardless, you cannot get a 5 year Schengen without a substantial performance history.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum you will get is a 1 year visa that too will depend on the embassy you are applying. Also it cannot extend beyond your UK Visa. I was living on Tier 1 and had applied for Schengen twice. The first time I got it for 1 year from the Czech embassy. The next time was just for the duration of the trip (2 weeks) when I applied to the Spanish embassy. Bear in mind that I had 6 Schengen visas already and that helped getting the 1 year visa.

Good trick is to mention that you will be traveling to Schengen states for the next 1 year and give a detailed itinerary for the office to believe you. You might not have tickets for your travels 8 months down the line but mention what are your plans. The cover letter should be convincing.